# Filter a dom object of input tags

Tags: javascript

I am building an object from a form that is currently rendered server side. I collect all the check boxes displayed in the image below and I am trying to sort them in a way that all the check boxes under each step (1, 2, 3 etc) is a single object based on the property `parentNode`.

Currently the `document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxes')`  fetches all the checkboxes in following format.

```
var newObj = [
    {
      name: 'one',
      parentNode: {
        id: 'stepOne'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'two',
      parentNode: {
        id: 'stepTwo'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'three',
      parentNode: {
        id: 'stepOne'
      }
    },
]
```

The new object should be:

```
var newObj = {
    stepOne: [
      {
        name: 'one',
        parentNode: {
          id: 'stepOne'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'three',
        parentNode: {
          id: 'stepOne'
        }
      },
    ],
    stepTwo: [
      {
        name: 'two',
        parentNode: {
          id: 'stepTwo'
        }
      },
    ]
}
```

Usually I do something like this:

```
let stepOne = function(step) {
  return step.parentNode.getAttribute('id') === 'stepOne';
}

let stepTwo = function(step) {
  return step.parentNode.getAttribute('id') === 'stepTwo';
}

let allTheStepOnes = fetchCheckBoxes.filter(stepOne);
```

But filter doesn't work on dom object and this seems inefficient as well.

[image: image here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) we can reduce your current array into the new structure.

```
return newObj.reduce(function(acc, item) {
```

If `acc[item.parentNode.id]` has been defined before, retrieve this.  Otherwise set it to an empty array:

```
acc[item.parentNode.id] = (acc[item.parentNode.id] || [])
```

Add the `item` to the array and then return it:

```
acc[item.parentNode.id].push(item);
return acc;
```

We set the accumulator as `{}` to start with.

---

Snippet to show the workings.

```js
var newObj = [{
  name: 'one',
  parentNode: {
    id: 'stepOne'
  }
}, {
  name: 'two',
  parentNode: {
    id: 'stepTwo'
  }
}, {
  name: 'three',
  parentNode: {
    id: 'stepOne'
  }
}, ];

var newOrder = function(prevList) {
        return prevList.reduce(function(acc, item) {
            acc[item.parentNode.id] = (acc[item.parentNode.id] || [])
            acc[item.parentNode.id].push(item);
            return acc;
        }, {});
    }
    
console.log(newOrder(newObj));
```

Comment: Is there a way to loop through the newOrder object? I need to loop through the result and fetch only some of the data.

Comment: `newOrder` is an anonymous function. You can use it as a regular function e.g. `var myNewList = newOrder(newObj )`. Then you can iterate over `myNewList`

Answer (score 2):

Proper way of doing this is a `forEach` loop and using associative arrays like this:

```
let newObject = {};

originalObject.forEach((item)=>{
    let step = item.parentNode.id
    if (newObj[step] === undefined) {
        newObj[step] = []
    }
    newObj[step].push(item)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This function should do the trick

```
function mapObj(obj) {
    var result = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        var e = obj[i];
        result[e.parentNode.id] = result[e.parentNode.id] || [];
        result[e.parentNode.id].push(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```